# How to change the format of the nested payload?

Tags: python, django

I want to change my json payload from:

```
{
    "grade": "ten",
    "studentdlList": [
        {
            "studentdetail": {
                "name": "mw",
                "rollno": 19
            }
        },
        {
            "studentdetail": {
                "name": "battery",
                "rollno": 44
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

To the form below, because the first one becomes too complex and redundant:

```
{
    "grade": "ten",
    "studentdlList": [
            "studentdetail": {
                "name": "mw",
                "rollno": 19
            }
        ,
            "studentdetail": {
                "name": "battery",
                "rollno": 44
            }

    ]
}
```

To achieve the result my serializers are below:

```
class SerializerTemp(serializers.Serializer):
    name =  serializers.CharField()
    rollno =  serializers.IntegerField()

class Studentserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    studentdetail = SerializerTemp(source="*")

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('studentdetail',)

class SiteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    studentdlList = Studentserializer(many = True)

    class Meta:
        model = Grade
        fields = ("grade", "studentdlList")
```

The last serializer also has update and create(which I haven't put here). How can I possibly change my payload to the specified form so that it is less redundant and more clearer?

Comment: Your expected output is not valid JSON. It is like the input except that you removed some required braces.

Comment: That is right, that I removed the braces, that is what I was trying to achieve!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As being said in the comments the example provided isn't a valid JSON. What you got here is a list of objects and therefore the brackets are needed to explicit say that is an object:

```
{
    "grade": "ten",
    "studentdlList": [
        {
            "studentdetail": {
                "name": "mw",
                "rollno": 19
            }
        },
        {
            "studentdetail": {
                "name": "battery",
                "rollno": 44
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

You can change your code to:

```
class Studentserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):  
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('name', 'rollno',)

class SiteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    studentdlList = Studentserializer(many = True)

    class Meta:
        model = Grade
        fields = ("grade", "studentdlList")
```

To produce something like:

```
{
    "grade": "ten",
    "studentdlList": [
        {
            "name": "mw",
            "rollno": 19
        },
        {
            "name": "battery",
            "rollno": 44
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I can already achieve the recommended json output, thanks though!